# Making Leaflet tooltip clickable

Tags: javascript, event-handling, click, leaflet

I want to add **tooltips** on a Leaflet map (without markers) and make them clickable. The following code adds a tooltip but it's not clickable:

```
var tooltip = L.tooltip({
        direction: 'center',
        permanent: true,
        interactive: true,
        noWrap: true,
        opacity: 0.9
    });
tooltip.setContent( "Example" );
tooltip.setLatLng(new L.LatLng(someLat, someLon));
tooltip.addTo(myLayer);
tooltip.on('click', function(event) {
    console.log("Click!");
});
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To receive clicks on a `L.Tooltip` object, you'll need to :

- set up a listener on the associated DOM object :

  ```
  var el = tooltip.getElement();
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
     console.log("click");
  });
  ```
- remove the [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) property set on that element:

  ```
  var el = tooltip.getElement();
  el.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
  ```

A demo so far

```js
var map = L.map(document.getElementById('map')).setView([48.8583736, 2.2922926], 4);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var tooltip = L.tooltip({
    direction: 'center',
    permanent: true,
    interactive: true,
    noWrap: true,
    opacity: 0.9
});
tooltip.setContent( "Example" );
tooltip.setLatLng(new L.LatLng(48.8583736, 2.2922926));
tooltip.addTo(map);

var el = tooltip.getElement();
el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("click");
});
el.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js"></script>
   
<div id='map'></div>
```

If you want to create a component or listen directly to a tooltip object, you can extend `L.Tooltip` to bake those alterations directly into the definition:

```
L.ClickableTooltip = L.Tooltip.extend({
    onAdd: function (map) {
        L.Tooltip.prototype.onAdd.call(this, map);

        var el = this.getElement(),
            self = this;

        el.addEventListener('click', function() {
            self.fire("click");
        });
        el.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    }
});

var tooltip = new L.ClickableTooltip({
    direction: 'center',
    permanent: true,
    noWrap: true,
    opacity: 0.9
});
tooltip.setContent( "Example" );
tooltip.setLatLng(new L.LatLng(48.8583736, 2.2922926));
tooltip.addTo(map);

tooltip.on('click', function(e) {
    console.log("clicked", JSON.stringify(e.target.getLatLng()));
});
```

And a demo

```js
L.ClickableTooltip = L.Tooltip.extend({

    onAdd: function (map) {
        L.Tooltip.prototype.onAdd.call(this, map);

        var el = this.getElement(),
            self = this;

        el.addEventListener('click', function() {
            self.fire("click");
        });
        el.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    }
});


var map = L.map(document.getElementById('map')).setView([48.8583736, 2.2922926], 4);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var tooltip = new L.ClickableTooltip({
    direction: 'center',
    permanent: true,
    noWrap: true,
    opacity: 0.9
});
tooltip.setContent( "Example" );
tooltip.setLatLng(new L.LatLng(48.8583736, 2.2922926));
tooltip.addTo(map);

tooltip.on('click', function(e) {
    console.log("clicked", JSON.stringify(e.target.getLatLng()));
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js"></script>
   
<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: I added `el.title = this.options.title;` to allow titles functionality.

Comment: How can you access the tooltip element inside the event listener? It only seems to be possible to get the html element but getting the actual tooltip object, for example to get its coordinates, seems to not be possible.

Comment: @Chris In the `ClickableTooltip` component, it's available as `target` in the event object. I've modified my example

Answer (score 6):

Easy solution: set the `interactive` property to true:

[tooltip interactive](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tooltip-interactive)

in react-leaflet

```
<Tooltip interactive={true}><Tooltip />
```

Comment: Most simple solution for the question asked, did exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

new L.Tooltip().setLatLng([]).addTo(map).bindTooltip(your html, {permanent: true,interactive: true,direction: 'center',className: 'yourclassname'});